# Self hosted signalR : How to identify the hosted signalR service is available for client access

Tags: signalr-hub

I have an application using signalR. How can I make sure the signalR service is available for client access. Currently, we hosting signalR service from console application. If console application is live, we assumed signalR service is available for client access. any other better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Create a small client app, run it every minute as a scheduled task and let it check if the service can be reached (send a special package and let the server give a respond). If no respond within X amount of seconds, send an email or restart the server app.